# How to get select elements that are not multiple?

Tags: jquery

There is a `select` element which is `multiple` and an ordinary `select` element :

```
<select multiple="">
    <option>1aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>1aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>1aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
    <option>1aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>2bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option>2bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option>2bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
    <option>2bbbbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
</select>
```

How to get select elements that are **not** multiple ?

Comment: Do you want to get the selected items in a multi-select box once a user makes a change? Or are you asking how how to use a selector to attach and event listener to the select?

Comment: for your information you do not need to add =" " after multiple. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an attribute selector (`[attribute]`) and the negation with `:not()`

```
$('select:not([multiple])')
```

That's the selector in jQuery.